# Claiming a domain for Facebook Insights

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-insights

I've added the required meta tags (as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) on a test environment, but when I use the dashboard to claim the domain, it gives an error indicating that no admin data could be found at the root.

Any idea what I've done wrong / why it isn't working?

See test site here: http://www.test.bbc.co.uk

Thanks very much,

Aodh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an `fb:admins` meta tag there, there's an `fb:page_id` tag but that's deprecated and if it worked for you before, it will stop doing so very soon - it was scheduled for removal on May 2nd 2012

BTW, you really should have included your meta tags in the question, it's quite difficult to see the issue from the question you've asked, it could easily have been closed as off-topic

Comment: Thanks Lgy, here are the meta tags I see on the page above: <meta property="fb:admins" content="297814326937641" /> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="187214818032936" />

Comment: You must have special logic for the Facebook user agent - here's what I see there: http://pastebin.com/LexEWq1p - it definitely still has `<meta property="fb:page_id" content="228735667216" />` and no fb:admins tag

Comment: The debug tool may just be following the og:url redirect back to the production site and scraping the tags there

Comment: Thanks Igy!, yep, we have special logic for showing different editions of the site based on location and the meta-tags weren't in the international edition! :)