# Ideal solution to deprecated use of fb:page_id to claim a domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-insights

I have been asked to claim a domain for a brand. We used to do this by using

```
<meta property="fb:page_id"content="%page_id_here%" />
```

This would automatically give admins of the relevant Facebook page access to the domain insights. Facebook will no longer validate the ownership of domains like this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347937/the-app-id-specified-within-the-fbapp-id-meta-tag-was-invalid)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724036/claiming-a-domain-for-facebook-insights)) and you must use `fb:admin` or `fb:app_id`.

Obviously `fb:app_id` will be the preferred way to do this, but does that mean we have two sets of user permissions, one for the Facebook page and one for the Facebook app created just for the domain?

Is there any easy way to make them one and the same?

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the insights page.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234,1235" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />
```

fb:admins can take a value of a single user ID or a comma-separated list of user IDs.
fb:app_id can take a value of a single app ID.

You lose admin automation of access by having to manually add each user-id, but gain the "do both".

Comment: Please read the question. This was already know when the question was written and is the crux of it!

Comment: "Is there any easy way to make them one and the same?" - primary question answered of how to do both. The easy-street automation that you're after no longer exists, but is simple enough to replicate by dynamically inserting the id of anyone with admin rights.